# associating to an encrypted ssid from mac os x command line

Tags: macos, ssh, automation

I have a bunch of macbook pro and air laptops which are being controlled through SSH. 
At this point I need to make them associate to an encrypted SSID. The command that I use is: 
`sudo networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 test-ssid 12345678` where `test-ssid` is the ssid that we connect to and `12345678` is the password.

When I issue this command through SSH it halts and a pop-up window appears on the laptop GUI where it says: "networksetup wants to access key "test-ssid" in your keychain with the options "Always Allow", "Deny" and "Allow"

Is there a way to make this window not appear and have the laptop simply connect to the ssid? I don't have a regular access to the laptop GUI and the SSID names constantly change so I can't really manually hit accept every time I need to connect a bunch of laptops.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an issue with the older OS X versions. Works fine on Yosemite which I was hesitant to upgrade to.